# Will socket send and receive call block till the complete message is transferred?

Tags: linux, sockets

We set the following options for a TCP/IP connect socket.   The value set for SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF options is 10240. The buffer size passed to recv and send calls is 1024.

Will the recv call always wait for getting 1024 bytes before returning? The sender sends packets having size 1024

Will the send call always wait for sending 1024 bytes before returning?

Should I set any other options for preventing the calls return before transferring the bytes specified?

```
setsockopt(*p_sockwk, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&reuseaddr,   (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
    setsockopt(*p_sockwk, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_SNDBUF,    (void*)&sendbufsize, (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
    setsockopt(*p_sockwk, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_RCVBUF,    (void*)&recvbufsize, (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
    setsockopt(*p_sockwk, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,  (void*)&delay,       (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
```

Comment: @ErikAlapää Very helpful. The whole book? And why the latest edition? What was wrong with the earlier ones? Please.

Comment: @EJP I just get annoyed when the people who asked questions have not made even the smallest attempt at grasping the idea behind an API and a protocol. For the book, the earlier editions are some of the best programming books ever written, but using the latest one give you up-to-date material on e.g. ipv6 and threading.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Recommending an entire book may mitigate your annoyance but it isn't actually a useful response to the question.

Comment: @EJP A reasonably intelligent person should be able to find the answer about TCP socket recv() within 10 minutes of opening the book. End of debate as far as i am concerned.

Comment: @ErikAlapää  A reasonably intelligent person should be able to find the answer without opening or even having the book at all. Nothing against the book, but your comments here about it are futile.

Answer (score 0):

> Will socket send and receive call block till the complete message is transferred?

You are using TCP, and there is no such thing as a message in TCP.

> We set the following options for a TCP/IP connect socket. The value set for SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF options is 10240. The buffer size passed to recv and send calls is 1024.
>
> Will the recv call always wait for getting 1024 bytes before returning?

No. This is documented.

> The sender sends packets having size 1024

Irrelevant.

> Will the send call always wait for sending 1024 bytes before returning?

In blocking mode, yes, unless there has been an interrupt.

> Should I set any other options for preventing the calls return before transferring the bytes specified?

There aren't any.

```
setsockopt(*p_sockwk, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&reuseaddr,   (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
```

Nothing to do with sending or receiving.

```
setsockopt(*p_sockwk, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_SNDBUF,    (void*)&sendbufsize, (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
setsockopt(*p_sockwk, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_RCVBUF,    (void*)&recvbufsize, (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
```

Set these larger than the defaults if you like, but they won't affect the behaviour you're asking about.

```
setsockopt(*p_sockwk, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,  (void*)&delay,       (socklen_t)sizeof(socklen_t));
```

This might or might not help but there are no guarantees.

If you want to fill the buffer on reading you have to loop.